# How does File Upload work on a server?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have the following problem: I have a client who will upload an Excel file online. This Excel file will need to be imported to a database table, which I can do using the `openrowset` command. Once it has been imported, I can display the data using a `GridView`.

Now, I have referred http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/ASPNET20FileUpload.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478971.aspx, but in both of them, the upload folder (destination) is hardcoded. How can I change this to reflect the file's destination to be on the server? And, once this is done, how can I then use `openrowset` to extract the contents of the Excel fie?

Additionally, how can I emulate the entire process on my machine before it is deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your file on server like..

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/temp/xyz.xlsx"));
```

and then set that in connection string like..

`connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/temp/xyz.xlsx"); Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";`

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Thanks! :) I'm guessing that `~/temp/xyz.xlsx` refers to the physical path of the file, or is it the other way around? That is, it refers to a folder on the server, where the file has been directed to be uploaded? Please enlighten me as I am new to this. Thanks! :)

Comment: It will always save the file to your Root/temp Directory of your application whether you will application run in your local machine or on server. ~ sign , it will locate root folder and Server.mappath, map to your absolute path.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Hey, what about my last question? How can I actually emulate and test this on my local machine, before actual deployment?

Comment: If you follow my answer, it will work on local and server as well.